# Filtering by a column on one of the joined tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select statement that returns some data I need:

```
  Select top 100 cnb.ndc_id, cnb.contract_num_val, cnb.quote_price, cnb.eff_dt, cnb.end_dt, cnb.discount_pct, cnb.rebate_pct, cnb.[CONTRACT_NDC_BRG_ID]
  from [NDC_ATTR] ndc 
  INNER JOIN CONTRACT_NDC_BRG cnb
  ON ndc.attr_val=cnb.NDC_ID
  where ndc.field_id=69
```

[image]

The last column is called CONTRACT_NDC_BRG_ID and I want to add it to the where clause.

Here you can see that id: 19977 is on the [CONTRACT_NDC_BRG]:

[image]

But when I try to add the where clause I get no results:

```
  Select top 100 cnb.ndc_id, cnb.contract_num_val, cnb.quote_price, cnb.eff_dt, cnb.end_dt, cnb.discount_pct, cnb.rebate_pct, cnb.[CONTRACT_NDC_BRG_ID]
  from [NDC_ATTR] ndc 
  INNER JOIN CONTRACT_NDC_BRG cnb
  ON ndc.attr_val=cnb.NDC_ID
  where ndc.field_id=69 and cnb.[CONTRACT_NDC_BRG_ID] = 19977
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: But it doesn't meet the other conditions in the `where` clause (or `on` clause) so it is filtered out.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can you show the SQL so I understand what you mean? If you look at the top sql both the where and on clause return results.

Comment: what data type is [CONTRACT_NDC_BRG]?

Comment: @asemprini87 CONTRACT_NDC_BRG is a table. CONTRACT_NDC_BRG_ID is an int.

Comment: Does NDC_ID on cnb table (i.e. 00591533701) has a match on ndc table?

Comment: @Gi1ber7 Yes, it does.